# EF4 Update Entity Without First Getting Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

How can I update an entity without having to make a call to select it. If I supply the key for the entity, should it not know to update after SaveChanges() is called on the ObjectContext.

I currently do this:

```
var user = context.Users.Single(u => u.Id == 2);
user.Username = "user.name";
user.Name = "ABC 123";
context.SaveChanges();
```

That works, but forces a select. Because I know the `Id`, why can't I do something like this:

```
var user = new User();
user.Id = 2;
user.Username = "user.name";
user.Name = "ABC 123";
context.UpdateObject(user);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Also, it's important that *only* the affected properties that are changed be updated. Is this possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe following code work fine.

```
var user = new User();
user.Id = 2;
context.Users.Attach(user);

user.Username = "user.name";
user.Name = "ABC 123";

context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: That doesn't actually *update* the object in the database. It adds it to the list of users though.

Comment: Calling `context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(user).ChangeState(EntityState.Modified);` does perform the update...

Comment: Do you change the Name property after "context.Users.Attach(user);"?

Comment: Yup, my mistake. This works great modifying the properties *after* the `Attach()` and when a property is modified, it only updates the *changed* property. Thanks!

Comment: It should be noted though that if you did a `foreach` on `context.Users` that you would see the `User` *not* filled with the other properties.

Comment: This is essentially that same methodology as this post from the EF team, no need to round trip it. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/03/27/tip-9-deleting-an-object-without-retrieving-it.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in a somewhat artificial way, by adding the entity and changing the EntityState to Modified:

```
var user = new User();
user.Id = 2;
user.Username = "user.name";
user.Name = "ABC 123";

context.AddToUsers(user);
ObjectStateEntry userEntry = context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(user);
userEntry.ChangeState(EntityState.Modified);

context.SaveChanges();
```

In this way you will be telling the ObjectContext to find an entry with Id = 2 and update it rather than adding a new entry to the database.

Comment: Ok that's cool. The works but *one* problem. What if I only want to change the `Name` property. I don't want all the fields to cause an update. Is this a limitation with EF?

Answer (score -1):

Didn't you have to select it anyway to get it's data to edit?
If you cache it it won't cost you anything getting it again when you save it.

Comment: In a typical web app you do the select, generate a page containing the Id's, and "forget about it". After the user updates the info and submits the form, you get back the Id and the new data. This is when you want to JUST update, rather than fetch the data you don't need one extra time before updating.

Comment: @Yakimych - Yeah that's exactly the situation that I'm working with. I don't really need to do a trip to the db to select it even though I have the data.