# Entity Framework 3.5 - how to update row without first loading it from database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

This is my current code to update a field in database

```
private void SaveUser(User user)
{
   USER UserObj = _db.USERs.First(i => i.USER_ID == user.USER_ID);
   UserObj.NAME = user.NAME;
   _db.SaveChanges();
}
```

This works fine. However, I want to change two things

1) Can I skip the loading of the row from DB first? i.e. this line `USER UserObj = _db.USERs.First(i => i.USER_ID == user.USER_ID);`

2) If there are 20 fields to update, how can I set all of them at once? Or I'll have to write all 20 assignments myself?

Thanks

Comment: does you mean update same fields(properties) of 20 records(entities) or 20 fields of one entity?

Comment: @Miroprocessor, I mean 20 fields of one entity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit** - samples modified for EFv1 - it answers both your questions:

You are looking for this:

```
private void SaveUser(User user)
{
    // Attach dummy entity - it must have only primary key property and EntityKey 
    // property assigned
    _db.USERs.Attach(new User() { ... });
    // Apply current values to dummy entity - this will mark the entity as modified
    // and it will also mark all properties (except key and store generated) as modified
    _db.ApplyPropertyChanges("UserSetName", user);
    _db.SaveChanges();
}
```

There is some difference between `EntityObject`s (today mostly obsolete) and POCOs (only EFv4) where POCO simply updates if it is marked as modified but `EntityObject` doesn't. It will update only if properties differ to its original state or if property is manually set as modified in `ObjectStateEntry`.

Selectively defining which properties must be updated is the same as manually assigning them:

```
private void SaveUser(User user)
{
    _db.USERs.Attach(user);
    ObjectStateEntry entry = _db.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(user);
    entry.SetModifiedProperty("PropertyName");
    // set other properties
    _db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Btw. have you heard about naming conventions?

Comment: _db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState is not working in EF 3.5

Comment: I modified samples for EFv1 but the best way you can do is upgrade to EFv4 because EFv1 is more like alpha version.

Comment: I can't move to EF4 due to project limitations. 
The first function you suggested is not saving anything. Seem like you missed something.

Comment: If the project limitation is .NET 3.5 selecting EF as data access technology wasn't good decision.

Answer (score 0):

If you are updating a User that already exists, you should already be working with that user pulled from the database. For example, if you have a business rule that the user can update their first name on the page, you should first: Fetch the User by their ID, perform the update like you are doing, and then save the user back out. You will also get the benefits of doing validation on the object and it doesn't cost much to do the fetch.

That wasn't really your question, but I thought it worth pointing out (that it is normal and okay to pull from the db). If you don't want to pull from the db, I am sure there is someway you can write and ad-hoc query, but perhaps not through the Entity Framework. For part 2, I don't see any way for you to update 20 fields without telling the EF what those 20 fields are. It needs to know what it is going to update at some level.

I know some parts of this answer may be unsatisfying, but overall I am suggesting working with the framework rather than against it.

Comment: please check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204020/ef4-update-entity-without-first-getting-entity), its answer says yes we can update an entity without getting it first from db

Comment: @skaz, yes I did get record from db, and filled the form to let user edit the fields. Then on submit, I need to save changes, but at time I can not use the last context when I fetched the row from db. And I think there must be a way to do it without fetching again.

And also, if there are plenty of fields in entity, which I have already in an object of entity class, there must be some way to use that instead of manually setting all properties again.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to update stuff without first loading it from the db, you will have to create a stored procedure and map that to your context (or use something entirely different from Entity Framework).
2. If you retrieve the object from the database and update 20 fields before calling `SaveChanges()`, all the changes will be flushed to the database in *one* transactional operation, so they will essentially be updated "all at once".

Answer (score 0):

for first part of your question check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204020/ef4-update-entity-without-first-getting-entity), it do what you need but you must know the primary key of the entity that you will update

for the second part you have to tell your context which entity you will update and which fields(properties) will be assigned with new values but the most interesting thing is you will hit your database just one time to run your updates by calling `SaveChanges()` method