# In EF4 unable to Update Entity Without First Getting Entity

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4, ado.net

When I update `CustomerName` using this code, `CustomerDesc` becomes NULL and vice versa. I Implemented the solution found in
[EF4 Update Entity Without First Getting Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204020/ef4-update-entity-without-first-getting-entity)

```
using (var dbMdl = new TestDBEntityModel())
    {

        Customer pr1 = new Customer();
        pr1.CustomerId = 1;
        if(pr1.EntityState == EntityState.Detached)
            dbMdl.Customers.Attach(pr1);
       // pr1.CustomerName = "Changed!";
        pr1.CustomerDesc = "Changed!";
        dbMdl.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(pr1,        System.Data.EntityState.Modified); 
        dbMdl.SaveChanges();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through online tutorials, I solved it by removing `dbMdl.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(pr1, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);` and it worked as expected.